# My services manager/locator. Can I inject it or is it only supposed to create services?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

Ok so I have this services manager/locator/factory object which creates and manages my single instance objects like my logger, http request, http response, router etc etc.

In my startup/bootstrap file I just instantiate it and start my services:

```
$services = new Services();

$logger = $services->getService('logger');
$security = $services->getService('security');
$auth = $services->getService('auth');
$router = $services->getService('router');
etc...
```

It knows each services dependencies and easily creates the objects like a factory.

The thing is my `Auth` class for example, if that ever somehow needs two more dependencies in a few months I just have to:

1. Modify the method in my `Services` class which instantiates the `Auth` class.
2. Modify the constructor in my `Auth` class and add in the two new dependencies.

It would take less than five minutes.

This `$services` object also instantiates my controller. Every controller has 1 dependency (at the moment), the `View`.

The problem with this is that when I create even 20 more controllers, all obviously with the same dependencies, and then in a few months I need to add two more dependencies to the controllers I will have to:

1. Modify the method in my `Services` class which instantiates the `Controller` class.
2. Modify the constructor of **every** Controller class and add in the two new dependencies.

I know it would work if I created the controller independently outside of the services manager/locator/factory object and instead injected the `$services` object into the controller so then every controller I make only has one dependency. I could make a million of them and if another dependency came along I wouldn't have to go and change all of the controller files but is this ok?

I feel like it would be injecting to much into the controller when it only needs one or two services from the service manager and also it sort of hides the controllers dependencies from you, they are not as visible as if you were injecting them into the constructor.

What is your opinion on this? and what do you think I should do?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question... but if you have a new dependency that you need to implement in every Controller, why don't you add it to the parent Controller class?... I think a good class hierarchy should prevent you from having to duplicate code across all your controllers. Maybe if you posted some sample code of how you're dealing with depedencies in your `Services` and controller classes it could help us understand what you need.

Comment: @tereško Haha I'm about 15 minutes into that video. Found it from your "How should a model be structured in MVC" post which is very good. @Barto I get what you are saying. I had a constructor in every controller which had `parent::__construct(Dependency1, 2...);` but now I am going to get rid of those and just use the base controllers constructor to set any dependencies so in the future it's simple to add any new dependencies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a controller factory (or method), which you use inside your services class.
As an argument you could pass in the class name, e.g.:

```
$controller = $this->controllerFactory->create('Foo\BarController');
$controller->setAnotherDependency($baz);
```

Additional dependencies, which are not shared by all controllers, you can add through setters.

Btw: Why not use a dependency container like [Pimple](https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple) or [Symfony2 DIC](https://github.com/symfony/DependencyInjection)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I use the Symfony2 DIC. I've got it figured out now I think.